# Starting Index of Arrays in C# and VB.Net

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

Have a look at the following code.,

**C#**

```
 string[] testString = new string[jobs.Count];
```

**Equivalent VB.Net**

```
Dim testString() As String = New String(jobs.Count - 1) {}
```

Why it is taking 'jobs.Count - 1' instead 'jobs.Count' in vb.net while creating new arrays?

Comment: Please review your question. Both examples do not make sense. They are both not defined as arrays.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In VB.NET the number in the array declaration means "max index", but in C# it means "number of elements"

Answer (score 6):

In C# the array has the number of elements you provide:

```
string[] array = new string[2]; // will have two element [0] and [1]
```

In VB.NET the array has the number of elements you provide, plus one (you specify the max index value):

```
Dim array(2) As String // will have three elements (0), (1) and (2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because with your `C#` code sample,

```
string testString = new string[jobs.Count];
```

That's a constructor of creating an array of string.

While with the VB.Net example,

```
Dim testString As String = New String(jobs.Count - 1) {}
```

You are referring with a new `String` object with length of string declared in the parenthesis.

If you want to create an array of `String` in VB.Net it must be like this:

```
Dim testString (jobs.Count) As String
```

see supporting links below: 
[VB.Net](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-array-vbnet)
[C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-array)