# DataGridView Count Rows to assign height

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datagridview

i've have a DataGridView where i have a total of 11 rows,
i have to assign the same height to all off the rows so i tried this:

```
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Height = 20
    Next
```

but it gives me an index error:
- Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count-1
```

VB.net is zero based

Comment: See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875681/starting-index-of-arrays-in-c-sharp-and-vb-net